# botframework handling attachments per user and conversation

Tags: botframework

In my bot I would like to accept attachments from users.
I know how to receive them in :

```
 public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
        {        
            if (message.Type == "Message")
            {
                if (message.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var afile in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        lstFiles.Add(afile.ContentUrl);
                    }                                  
                }
```

what I am doing here is storing them as they arrive in lstFiles that is list of strings private to class MessagesController : ApiController, this way I know I can have those files and their URLs

When users finishes answering the questions ( I am using FormFlow) in the Do event I store his input in Azure storage table

```
     internal static IDialog<VGMData> MakeRootDialog()
            {         
              return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(VEMData.BuildForm))                
                           .Do(async (context, order) =>
                           {
    var completed = await order;                              
    StoreAndSendEmailConfirmations(completed);
    await context.PostAsync("And I am done... ..");
}
```

I can not understand how can I have access to attached files in the .Do function so that I can initiate download and subsequent storage in azure blob for files submitted by user and within his conversation. Only thing I seem to have is 'context' and 'order' that is user data replies but without attachment files.
I can get there lstFiles, but I am afraid it may contain files from different simultaneous users and conversations.

thanks in advance,
Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider storing the list of attachments in the PerUserPerConversation data bag. In that way you can ensure that you will be retrieving the data related to the user participating in that conversation.

[Here](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/tracking-bot-state/#navtitle) is the documentation around how the bot track state.

Comment: Thank you, I read the documentation on bot state before asking. Where my confusion comes is that i actually never use ReplyMesage, all goes via FormFlow and my problem is that I do not know how I can have access to message data bag from within .Do event at the end

Comment: I understood, In .Do event I have access via context.PerUserInConversationData Thanks for your advise.